# I can't insert data into MySQL table with Jquery, PHP and AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am trying to get some input fields, and with AJAX and jQuery, insert the data in the MySQL table, by pressing the send button, but doesn't work for me.

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>    
<head>
    <title>Ejercicio</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#send").click(function () {
                var titular = $("#titular").val();
                var descripcion = $("#descripcion").val();
                console.log(titular);
                console.log(descripcion);
                $.ajax({
                    url: "ejercicio.php",
                    data: {
                        "titular": titular,
                        "descripcion": descripcion
                    },
                    method: "post",
                    cache: false
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>    
<body>        
        <div>
            <input id="titular" name="titular" type="text" placeholder="Titular">
        </div>
        <div>
            <input id="descripcion" name="descripcion" type="text" placeholder="Descripción">
        </div>
        <div>
            <button id="send">Enviar</button>
        </div>
    <span id="resultado"></span>
</body>    
</html>
```

And this is my PHP file:

```
<?php
    $conexion = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
    mysql_select_db("formulario", $conexion);

    $titular = $_POST["titular"];
    $descripcion = $_POST["descripcion"];

    //$sql = "INSERT INTO formulario (id, titular, descripcion, cuerpo, fecha, imagen) VALUES ('', '$titular', '$descripcion', '$cuerpo', '$fecha', $imagen)";
    $sql = "INSERT INTO formulario (id, titular, descripcion) VALUES ('', '$titular', '$descripcion')";
    mysql_query($conexion, $sql);
    mysql_close($conexion);        
?>
```

Comment: What is the actual question?

Comment: Yes you can. plz search on google

Comment: Please note that you are using deprecated PHP function this shouldn't prevent you from performing the task you want but it is recommended to move to MySQLi. `http://php.net/manual/fr/book.mysqli.php`

Comment: Do you have any error message ? Can you confirm the ajax is working ? (To confirm ajax is working, you can use some debug feature like [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/addon/firebug/)) and check in the console ? Do you have any PHP errors returned by Ajax ? (To display errors, add on top of your PHP file `ini_set('display_errors',1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1);`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is with your sql query

```
 $sql = "INSERT INTO formulario (id, titular, descripcion) VALUES ('', '$titular', '$descripcion')";
mysql_query($conexion, $sql);
```

If you have set your id column as auto increement then you need not to insert values to id coloumn as it will auto insert.
 try

```
 $sql = "INSERT INTO formulario (titular, descripcion) VALUES ('$titular', '$descripcion')";
mysql_query($conexion, $sql);
```

Comment: Hi sagar patro!, thanks for the answer, but I changed it, and it doesn't work :(. I'm trying to find the error but I haven't done it yet :(

Answer (score 0):

I assume the Ajax part is working.

In  you table formulario, `id` must be  `PRIMARY KEY` and `auto_increment`. Then juste insert without mentionning it :

```
INSERT INTO formulario (titular, descripcion) VALUES ('$titular', '$descripcion');
```

Comment: Hi ThinkTank!, thanks for the answer, but I changed it, and it doesn't work :(. Maybe the error is in the Ajax part, but I don't find it :(.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the position of parameters in mysql_query($conexion,$sql); to 
mysql_query($sql,$conexion);.Then it will works.

Comment: Hi surabhivin!, thanks for the answer. I changed it, and it doesn't work yet, I think the error is in the Ajax part but I'm trying to find it, and I Can't :(

Answer (score 0):

It's fixed! Opening the console, I found a new error:

XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Users/Jonathan/Desktop/ejercicio/ejercicio.php. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.

So searching in google I found some solutions that didn't work for me, so I installed netbeans, and with it, it works fine!

Thanks everybody for your help!